# Array of isClicked links Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

On my View I have many links, they contain a numbers - ratios of event . Its table where 3 columns and many rows.

```
    <div class="links">
        <div id="multiply">
            <table class="table_blur">
                @foreach (Models.Game game in Model)
                {
                <tr>
                    <td><a class="zxc">@game.win1</a></td>
                    <td><a class="zxc">@game.win2</a></td>
                    <td><a class="zxc">@game.draw</a></td>
                </tr>
                }
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>

<div class="menu_body" id="owl">

                    </div>
<div class="men" id="bw">

                    </div>
```

for Example @game.win1 = "2.21" its string

And I have function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var counter = 0;
        var clicks = 0;
        var links = document.getElementsByClassName("zxc");

        for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
            links[i].isClicked = false;
        }
        $('.links a').click(function () {
            if (clicks == 0) {
                counter++;
                $(this).isClicked = true;
                $(this).toggleClass('clicked');
            } else {
                counter--;
                $(this).isClicked = false;
                $(this).removeClass('clicked');
            }
            ++clicks;

            var arr = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
                if (links.isClicked) {
                    arr *= links[i].style.innerHTML;
                }
            }
            $("#owl").html(counter);
            $("#bw").html(arr);
        });
    });
</script>
```

**CSS**

```
a.clicked{
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

My question:

1. If link clicked, background change , but if this link click second time, background change in start position.
2. If link clicked , counter++ , but if this link click second time, counter--
   And its number need to show on my "owl" class.
3. If link clicked, value (ratio) need to show in bw class, and if other links isClicked too, ratio multiply to other ratio  (for Example 2.21*3.15).

Comment: We need: 1- full code 2- fiddle/codepen 3- read 1 and 2

Comment: What is your actual question? A requirement list is not a question.

Comment: 1. I did.   2- in my code, when I click first time counter++, but when I click second,third time or clicked on the other links counter only decreases.

Answer (score 0):

If link clicked, background change , but if this link click second time, background change in start position.

```
$('.links a').click(function(){
  if($(this).css("background-color") == "yellow")
    {
      $(this).css("background-color", "white");
    }
   else
    {
      $(this).css("background-color", "yellow");
    }
  counter++;
  $("#owl").html($(this).text + " Clicked " + counter);
  $("#bw").html(arr); //this one I don't know what you need..
});
```

Sorry I don't know really if this is what you need, but it do the change in back-ground, increment the counter and display the event on your "owl" element.

Comment: http://i67.tinypic.com/ayrjb7.png  . I want how to do this in this site(screen). All ratios - links. Bets selected - how many bets selected. total coeff - its multiply.  But if you click second time on this link Bets selected  decreases and background white.  Maybe its screen help